# How can I create an eWallet in PHP?

Tags: wallet, development, e-wallet, escrow

My experience with PHP is not the best, but it's good enough to learn and expand. I wish to create a Bitcoin eWallet for my website where it automatically creates a Bitcoin wallet for users. This wallet will also do other stuff, such as generate a new Bitcoin wallet every 24 hours or so.

I read through the running bitcoin but didn't understand much of it. I know many websites such as Blackmarket Reloaded have what I need but my website is no way related to drugs or that stuff, I'm just using their eWallet and escrow as an example of what I need.

I checked out many websites that provide APIs like this (such as StrongCoin) but all their APIs and files are too old or deleted.

How can I go to making this come true? Any steps?

Comment: This Instawallet-like wallet might give some useful info: http://blog.kangasbros.fi/?p=85

Answer (score 3):

1 - If you don't want to use third party systems, you will need a server to host bitcoind.

2 - Install Bitcoin-QT. In your [data directory](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory), create [`bitcoin.conf`](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Sample_Bitcoin.conf) with the following attributes (you will need more if you are trying to connect to bitcoind from outside of localhost):

> ```
> server=1
> rpcuser=username
> rpcpassword=password
> ```

3 - Use the [Bitcoin API](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list) to access any data you need. You will most likely need to use `accounts` in order to ensure proper money handling.

If you need further assistance, feel free to ask here, or [contact me](http://tiny.cc/ThePiachu) for more direct help at a reasonable price ;).